# TwiML - HTML - XHTML: live .wax file streaming to Twilio phone call

Tags: twilio

Does anybody have any idea if and/or how to stream a `.wax` file in Twilio's TwiML?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio doesn't support .wax files for audio content. You can find the documentation on the files we support here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play#nouns

Here is the list of suppoted audio formats and their MIME types:

```
audio/mpeg      mpeg layer 3 audio

audio/wav       wav format audio

audio/wave      wav format audio

audio/x-wav     wav format audio

audio/aiff      audio interchange file format

audio/x-aifc    audio interchange file format

audio/x-aiff    audio interchange file format

audio/x-gsm     GSM audio format

audio/gsm       GSM audio format

audio/ulaw      μ-law audio format
```